# Html link to open and reply to .eml file

Tags: html, outlook

I'd like to add a "Reply" button in my web application which can open a .eml email in the user's default mail application (eg Outlook), and hit "Reply".

mailto is clearly not an option since html bodies don't seem to be possible.

Any easy way to do this? Note that the server does have the .eml file

Comment: So what is the problem? Generating an eml file?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the problem is the number of clicks. If I just link to a downloadable file, the user has to click to download, click to open, click reply. Ideally I just want one button "Reply" which will do all of this.

Comment: Can't do that - nothing gets opened without the user consent.

Comment: I see - this is for an internal application, so we do have some control on the user's browsers.. It'll be very easy to ask them to hit "Allow page to run scripts", or maybe even install a browser plugin or something if that changes things - of course the less the user has to do the better